# What are the incidents represented on the map presented by Thunderbolt Ross?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In Captain America: Civil War what are the incidents/locations represented on the map presented by Thunderbolt Ross?

[image]

He explains what four represent:

1. New York (Avengers)
2. Washington D.C. (Captain America: The Winter Soldier)
3. Sokovia (Avengers: Age of Ultron)
4. Lagos (Captain America: Civil War).

But there are still five incidents that are unexplained in the film, what do the other dots represent?

Comment: i wonder if they included any attacks made public by "Mandarin" from Iron Man 3, and anything suspect from Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D

Comment: Nicholas, it could be possible that they added some of the "Mandarin" incidents but they didn't think it necessary to mention it in the film. Or that they are references to Agents of SHIELD episodes, they do go to Australia in an episode so it could be referring to that. Paulie, I don't think they are referencing things that haven't happened in the MCU yet.  They wouldn't reference things that haven't happened to justify their actions, they can't....and I don't think they are going back in time and setting some of the movies before Civil War.

Comment: I guess it's possible that they are events that could be flashbacks in future movies, that simply haven't been explained yet. I don't think they would jump back and set Doctor Strange before Civil War though. While it's possible I don't think it's likely that they reference events that appear as flashbacks in future films. I definitely don't think they are references to anything Doctor Strange related. It just doesn't seem to fit with what we know so far about the story.

Comment: I wonder why Hulk's rampage in Wakanda isn't on the map, especially since it called Black Panther into action in this very film.

Comment: I guess it's safe to assume that was part of the reason the Wakandans pushed the accords. But in the film they don't reference it and just cite the Lagos incident as their reason for pushing it. The main reason Black Panther takes action is really for revenge though, something he acknowledges at the end when talking to Zemo. It is curious why Wakanda was left off though. Also London and New Mexico don't feature despite what happened in the two Thor films.

Comment: The Hulk's rampage wasn't set in Wakanda...it was in South Africa as I recall

Comment: That's true...apparently. Odd. I could've sworn that sequence took place in Wakanda. Apparently it was only mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

Several of those dots represent things that did not happen in any MCU movie. It's *possible* that they represent things that happened on *Agents of SHIELD* but that would be unusual -- the movies have steadfastly refused to acknowledge that the TV shows exist. (Though this might be an "easter egg" type of crossover.)

The major incidents that we see happening in the movies that are likely represented on the map are:

- Northeast US: Washington DC (*The Winter Soldier*) and New York City (*Avengers*) as you mentioned.
- Southwest US: Possibly the *Iron Man 3* attacks by Mandarin (e.g. on Tony Stark's house?), or the *Ant Man* incidents in San Francisco.
- South America: In *The Incredible Hulk*, Hulk trashes a bottling plant in Rio de Janiero. The dot's in the wrong place for this, but it's the closest we have.
- Eastern Europe: Sokovia from *Age of Ultron*
- Western Africa: Lagos, from *Civil War*

The remainder represent locations that have no direct correlation to anything that happened in any of the movies. There are dots over what appears to be Cairo in Egypt, somewhere along the Russia/China border, southeast China around Kunming or Guiyang, and Adelaide in Australia.

There are hints of these places in *Agents of SHIELD* (particularly related to the "centipede project"), but nothing mentioned in any of the movies. Most likely they are just random dots added for flavor; remember that the Avengers have been actively hunting HYDRA for years by this point, with the idea being that they are *constantly* going into other countries and causing problems. It stands to reason that we didn't see every one of those incidents on-screen.

Comment: Looks more Amazonian, though. Sure there wasn't any shit going down in the Amazonas ever?

Comment: Another reason that it's likely not referring to any of the TV-shows would also be that *they're not about Avengers* afterall. If you want to argue that the Avengers mess everything up around the world, showing stuff some rogue SHIELD agents do is not helping your point.

Comment: well, during that speech, Ross mentioned the "increased number of enhanced people", not just Avengers, in the world, so it's possible his map includes other enhanced people causing problems. But it's a stretch.

Comment: I had thought that some may be references to events that happened in one of the shows. But I think you're right, I don't think they reference anything from them. Apart from the fact that they want to stay away from referencing the shows in the movies, I also can't think of many things that happen in the shows that you would put on par with the events that they cite in the film. Now I'm wondering why there aren't dots for certain incidents though. I would have thought they would have referenced New Mexico and/or London from the Thor movies.

Comment: I'm skeptical that they included the incident from _Incredible Hulk_, since the dot is in the wrong place; that would imply they're only showing incidents that happened after the Avengers formed.. but that doesn't explain the lack of _Thor 2_, especially if _Iron Man 3_ is on there.

Comment: Going back, the southwest US dot could also refer to the events in Iron Man. I think this makes more sense than it referring to the attack on Stark's house. This puts a splinter in the idea that they're referring to events after the Avengers formed. I don't think that would be the likely case regardless. Identifying some of the dot references seems almost impossible in either case.